# Efficient way to find the pixel coordinates in image for circle circumference intersection

Tags: python, image, coordinates, pixel

I would like to efficiently find the coordinates of the line described by the intersection between the circumference of a circle and an image (origin of circle is outside the image).  Right now I'm using a loop in python to start at one edge of the image and move through the image a step at a time.  Each step moves a certain distance (say 0.01 inches).  I calculate the angle needed to move that distance and then use polar geometry formulas to define the next pixel coordinate.  This all works just fine, however, it takes a long time.  I'm creating many of these lines through the image as the radius of the circle increases.

Is there a way to use a built in function or an array based formula so that I don't have to have so many steps in my algorithm?  Basically, what is the most efficient way to accomplish this in python 2?

Thanks,
rb3

Comment: 1) generate (x,y) point of circle with some density 2) hash the points to pixels 3) pixels with hits are the line you want

Comment: If you are calling mathematical functions in this loop (like sin(x) or cos(x)), caching the values for these functions may help your loops go faster.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the intersection of a circle and an image though, perhaps a diagram may help?

Answer (score 0):

```
# circle parameters 
x0 = -5
y0 = -5
R = 25
# image size
max_x = 100
max_y = 100
# sample points
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 2048) # make bigger if you have huge images
# the pixels that get hit
xy = list(set([xy for xy in zip( (R * cos(theta) - x0).astype(int), (R * sin(theta) - y0).astype(int)) if
               xy[0] >= 0 and xy[0] < max_x and xy[1] >= 0 and xy[1] < max_y]))
```